# Able to start multiple camel contexts per deployment

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, apache-camel, openjdk-11

We are migrating our application from Camel 2.x to 3.x (2.20.2 to 3.11.2). We are using `Spring XML` to create camel routes. There are 2 XML files with one camel context defined in each. We are bootstrapping these camel contexts using spring (see below screenshot).

[bootstrap camel contexts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYxcH.png)

As per the Camel 2.x to 3.x migration guide only one camel context is supported per deployment but when I deploy my application in tomcat, it starts all the routes present in both the camel contexts. What does it actually mean when camel documentation says that only one camel context is supported per deployment?

References:

- [How load multiple camel context in spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62471026/how-load-multiple-camel-context-in-spring)
- https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/camel-3-migration-guide.html#_multiple_camelcontexts_per_application_not_supported

Answer (score 0):

I suspect (never tried this) that the smart Camel simply puts all your routes in the default context.

You can check that with the `getRoutes()` method on the Camel context or in a debugging session.

The key question is: why did you create multiple contexts in your Camel 2 application?

Comment: As mentioned we are migrating our application. The existing application was designed with multiple camel contexts.

Comment: Well then, perhaps you simply don't NEED multiple Camel contexts. Were you able to check if my assumption is correct?